# Getting TNS :Connect timeout occurred in Oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

I have the below function and I am quite frequently getting the below errors when front end ( ADF ) calls this function to get count.
Different errors comes at different times.

I think sometimes the listener is down so it might occur but other errors ?It happens when user from front end click on the link and that link in turn calls this database function.

I'm not able to find the issue in the function :-(

```
   1) error "-12170 : ORA-12170: TNS:Connect timeout occurred"
   2) error "-12571 : ORA-12571: TNS:packet writer failure" 
   3) error "-12541 : ORA-12541: TNS:no listener
   4) error "-12514 : ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor
   5) error "-3113 : ORA-03113: end-of-file on communication channel
    ORA-02063: preceding line from DBLINK" 
   6) error "-2051 : ORA-02051: another session or branch in same transaction failed or finalized
    ORA-02063: preceding line from DBLINK"


FUNCTION GET_A (p_in IN VARCHAR2) RETURN NUMBER
    AS
     PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
     PRE_COUNT  NUMBER := NULL;

    BEGIN

      SELECT GET_B@DBLINK (p_in,NULL)INTO  PRE_COUNT FROM dual;
          COMMIT;
     --  dbms_lock.sleep(2);
       DBMS_SESSION.CLOSE_DATABASE_LINK('DBLINK');
        COMMIT;
            RETURN PRE_COUNT;

    EXCEPTION
     WHEN OTHERS
      THEN
      ROLLBACK;
      LOG_ERR ( p_cd => SQLCODE,p_msg => SQLERRM);
      RETURN -1;
END GET_A;
```

Comment: Those errors seem to generally indicate either a problem with the remote listener or with the network connection between the databases.  The fact that you're forcing a new network connection to be set up every time the function is called (a rather expensive operation and one that requires hitting the listener) rather than letting the network connection remain up certainly tends to increase the probability of error.  I'm also terribly unclear why you're using an autonomous transaction and/or committing when you haven't done anything to commit.

Comment: @JustinCave Without "commit" it was giving error.I don't recollect but certainly there was some issue without putting commit.I will check and get back.

Comment: I'm guessing that the `commit` was added because the function was declared to be automomous or the function was declared to be autonomous because someone needed the `commit`.  I'm not sure that I understand the point of having either in this context (or the `close_database_link` call) since you're just trying to call a function in a remote database.